# Why would a portable executable change after a clean and rebuild (ignoring timestamps)

Tags: windows, exe, portable-executable

I spent some time comparing hex diffs of an executable before and after a clean and rebuild, and there seem to be some sections that always change, no matter what.

I know that .NET injects some metadata, and the compiler inserts time stamps. Our internal hashing tool ignores those changes, but fails on other sections of the executable.

I don't think that the sections that keep changing our from our code.

Comment: Any tools a bit smarter than a hex editor?

Comment: Can you elaborate which fields were ignored in the hashing tool?

Comment: For one, the header for the debug directory kept changing ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/fKlb290.png)).

Note that the debug header starts with "RSDS" ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)).

The first three lines are the time stamp, which we handle already.

Answer (score 1):

The 16 varying bytes you point out in the comments are a UUID. There are some "variant" and "version" bits in the 7th and 8th byte of an GUID, which can be used to recognize them ([see RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4)).